# Rails ActiveAdmin: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::UsersController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to create button to change User `status:string` from `inactive` to `active` inside active admin show action. To do so I'm using `collection_action` with below code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :status

  collection_action :update_status, method: :post do
    user.update!(status: 'active')
    redirect_to user_path, notice: 'User status updated'
  end
```

Then I render custom partial `_show.html.erb`

```
<tr>
  <td colspan='2'>
    <% if @user.status == 'inactive' %>
      <%= link_to 'Activate user', update_status_admin_users_path %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
```

Here is what ActiveAdmin generated dynamically by `collection_action`

`bin/rails routes`

```
update_status_admin_users POST       /admin/users/update_status(.:format)                                                              admin/users#update_status
```

Instead of updating the data I'm getting an error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::UsersController#show
> Couldn't find User with 'id'=update_status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above error is because you are redirecting to `user_path` for which `id` parameter it require to redirect, and as you are using collection_action `id` parameter is missing.

If your intention is to update just one user, then use `member_action` instead of `collection_action`.

- using `resource`

```
  member_action : update_status, method: :put do
    resource.update!(status: 'active')
    redirect_to user_path, notice: 'User status updated'
  end
```

- with own finder

```
  member_action : update_status, method: :put do
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.update!(status: 'active')
    redirect_to user_path, notice: 'User status updated'
  end
```

```
  <td colspan='2'>
    <% if @user.status == 'inactive' %>
      <%= link_to 'Activate user', update_status_admin_user_path, method: :put %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/admin/users/1/update_status"`

Comment: @mr_muscle I missed to set `method` to link_to. I have updated the answer. could you please check now.

Comment: There should be also `user = User.find(params[:id])` as a first line of `member_action`

Comment: @mr_muscle oops my bad you can make use of `resource` instead of user then. I'll update my answer